# find adjacent alphanumeric number

Tags: xslt-1.0

My input xml

```
<namelist>
 <order>
     <name>JAMES</name>
      <accNo>10D</accNo>
 </order>
 <order>
      <name>ARAFAT</name>
      <accNo>07A</accNo>
 </order>
 <order>
       <name>anotherbranchaccount</name>
       <accNo>20J</accNo>
 </order>
 <order>
       <name>JAMES</name>
       <accNo>20K</accNo>
 </order>
 <order>
      <name>JOHN</name>
      <accNo>9A</accNo>
 </order>
 <order>
      <name>anotherbranchaccount</name>
      <accNo>10E</accNo>
 </order>
</namelist>

Expected output
JAMES 10D ANOTHERACCOUNT 10E
ARAFAT 07A
JAMES 20K ANOTHERACCOUNT 20J
```

My problem

I got to match with 'anotherbranchaccount'element which 'accNo' is adjacent to JAMES 'accNo' .There is no sequence like main account number then extra account node.
Give me solution. I dont have any idea about finding from alphanumeric format.because we have many alphanumeric comibanations like [A-Z][1 TO 100]
How to solve this issue? Please help me out.

Comment: `Give me solution` -> No. If you want to do some XML parsing, it suggest you to read this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java

Comment: No.Its not giving any solution..

Comment: A DOM XML Parser will help you to navigate in you XML document. For example it will allow you to get all `<order>` tags, then filter the ones which contain a tag `<name>` which have inner text `JAMES`.

Answer (score 0):

This Regular Expression will return true for your account number format:

```
"(^[0-9]{1,2})+([a-zA-Z]{1})$"
```

Comment: Which function I got to use in this case? whether compare() or translate(). How can i compare with accNo? Please elaborate this,actually i am very new to xslt and beginner as well