# Finding an XML node by its attribute value and updating in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

Let's say I have the following XML document:

```
<Offices>
  <Office name="P">
    <Counter>1000</Counter>
  </Office>
  <Office name="K">
    <Counter>1006</Counter>
  </Office>
</Offices>
```

With that document I need to perform the following in Java:

1. Parse the XML.
2. Get the value of `Counter` given a certain value for a `name` attribute.
3. Update the XML with a new value for `Counter` for exactly this `Office`.

For 2. I have considered using XPath but editing/updating the XML seems to be not that easy this way.

How could I go through the XML finding a certain office name and update its counter? The XML itself won't be large, only something like 20 office entries max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looking at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059411/1571550

It seems pretty straightforward and generic solution.

Comment: I like the JAXB approach.