# Given the first N bytes of a text file, how to determine if these bytes are XML or not?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Given `byte[] peek` where peek is `N` bytes from a text file, how can I determine if `peek` is XML?

Is it enough to just check for a `<` in the start of the string?

Comment: This is thoroughly documented [in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/).

Comment: *"Is it enough to just check for a < in the start of the string?"* Not even a little tiny bit.

Comment: ok i found it in the `F Autodetection of Character Encodings (Non-Normative)` section

Comment: Lest you get the wrong impression: I didn't downvote your question. Note that comments about "trolls" are neither efficacious nor constructive.

Comment: ok cool. there has got to be a java method written somewhere that takes `byte[]` and returns `is xml` right?

Comment: There will be when you write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the XML standard, your files should use `<?xml` to make it possible to tell if they are XML. If you have chosen not to follow that recommendation, there is no reliable way to tell. Some non-XML files will pass any test (by starting with `<`) that looks at small-N bytes. Others won't. Also note that a valid XML file may begin with a Unicode BOM character, so be sure to take that into account if you are going to go ahead and try this.

Answer (score 2):

To determine, does given string have XML format, you need a parser (for Java, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java)). This is the only way to get exact answer.

Checking first few bytes, in order to find `<?xml` only gives you assumptions, whether it is valid XML. But you cannot be absolutely sure until you parse it to the end.

Comment: I only have `N` bytes. and most of the xml files in my use case do not have `<?xml>` they would just start like this `<element>`

Comment: All I have so far is: `String peekStr = new String(peek); peekStr.contains("<?xml") || peekStr.contains("<")`

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza no matter how long string is, you still need to read it all to validate it as XML. If you read only first bytes and see `<element>`, you can only say "okay, in the beginning it looks like XML". Beyond these few bytes there may be any malformed data. This type of check isn't safe.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza I highly recommend to use full-qualified parser for your problem. This is more healthy way of program design, and I think, performance cost would be negligible.

Comment: A parser won't answer the 'small N' question, so I'm not sure  you're helping by suggesting it.

Comment: @bmargulies, on 'small N', answer would be "there is no way to guarantee this is XML". If we reduce question to "having limited access only to few first bytes, check if string is **NOT** XML", then yes, code above does something useful. We don't know the problem context, however, it is likely enough, these limitations are result of poor design, and answering straightly to this question, we only show author how to shoot himself in the foot more precisely.