# XML Parse - Issue with parsing text from specific Node

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Face an issue in parsing XML to extract data from a specific node. I referred to [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java) [Link2](https://www.journaldev.com/1240/java-xml-parser) [Link3](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152). Please note, am able to parse & get the data for other nodes in the below xml file like id, order_id etc. But for the below line / node, unable to extract the info of segment_id & instrument_id:

```
<trade segment_id="NSE-F&amp;O " instrument_id="NSE:INFRATEL17NOVFUT">
```

Not sure if the way the XML file is setup or the way I am trying to extract the data for that specific node is wrong. Hope the specific issue I face is clear.

**XML File:**

```
<contract_note version="0.1">
 <contracts>
  <contract>
   <id>CNT-17/18-5310750</id>
   <name>CONTRACT NOTE CUM BILL</name>
   <description>None</description>
   <timestamp>2017-11-01</timestamp>
   <trades>
      <trade segment_id="NSE-F&amp;O " instrument_id="NSE:INFRATEL17NOVFUT">
      <id>37513030</id>
      <order_id>1300000000352370</order_id>
      <timestamp>09:20:48</timestamp>
      <description>None</description>
      <type>buy</type>
      <quantity>1700</quantity>
      <average_price>444.2</average_price>
      <value>755140.0</value>
      </trade>
   </trades>
  </contract>
 </contracts>
</contract_note>
```

**Code:**

```
try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

        NodeList cNoteList = doc.getElementsByTagName("contract");
        Node nNode = cNoteList.item(0);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        for (int j = 1; j <= eElement.getElementsByTagName("trade").getLength(); j++) {
// Check if data can be read for Node - 'id'    
System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(j).getTextContent();
// Check if data can be read for segment_id & instrument_id         
System.out.println("Scrip: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("trade").item(0).getTextContent());
                }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**Edit:**
Corrected the xml file info provided above.

Comment: The & character is what is causing troubble. It should be escaped.

Comment: After some back-and-forth with OP, real question turns out to be a basic "how do I read XML attribute values in Java" question.  Closed as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you & my sincere apologies for not having searched the thread you cited.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Juan commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137646/xml-parse-issue-with-parsing-text-from-specific-node#comment81224657_47137646), your XML is bad.  Fix it by following the [**required XML escaping rules**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085) and replacing `segment_id="NSE-F&O "` with `segment_id="NSE-F&amp;O "`.

If you cannot change the XML, then see *[How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765194/how-to-parse-invalid-bad-not-well-formed-xml)* for options, but the best option is to fix the XML at the source.

Comment: Thanks, I opened the xml in Notepad now & notice it as segment_id="NSE-F&amp;O " So the file should be fine I presume.

Comment: Confused by your comment:   *Notice*?  Did you not fix it?  *Presume*?
 Have you not retested?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I had opened the XML in IE, which shows as segment_id="NSE-F&O ". But if I open the same XML in Notepad it is shown as segment_id="NSE-F&amp;O ". I have not made any changes to the XML file. But when I try to parse, am not able to read that data. Any other mistake which I am doing?

Comment: Please add the error message and stack trace to your question, along with a proper [mcve].

Comment: There is no error issued. But the output just reads as 'trade'. My expectation was it should read as 'trade segment_id="NSE-F&O " instrument_id="NSE:INFRATEL17NOVFUT"

Comment: Use `getAttributes()` for attributes.  Closing this question as a duplicate...