# How to parse contents of XML-elements that occur multiple times in a document

Tags: java, xml

I have a XML file, I'm reading it's content using *BufferedReader*, i then store some pieces of information in *String* using *substring*. See following code:

Load file, basically I take whole xml file and store it in String called *whole XML*

```
try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile), "UTF-8"));

                while ((line2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                      wholeXML= line2;


                   } catch (IOException ex2) {
                        System.out.println("Exception xml");
                    }
```

after that i use substring to get data i need for example:

```
String senderID = wholeXML.substring(wholeXML.indexOf("<q1:SenderID>")+13,wholeXML.indexOf("</q1:SenderID>"));`
```

This serves my purpose and workes just fine, but i'm having problem because one part in xml file is not static it's dynamic, like this:

```
q1:Attachment>  
<q1:AttachmentID>ba9727cc-a831-4ded-b88c-a00000041357</q1:AttachmentID>    
</q1:Attachment>       
-<q1:Attachment>   
<q1:AttachmentID>c0773e77-e011-484e-a1e9-b00000131099</q1:AttachmentID>  
</q1:Attachment>     
-<q1:Attachment>   
<q1:AttachmentID>08f57403-2feb-443c-8dd4-b00000131103</q1:AttachmentID>
</q1:Attachment> 
-<q1:Attachment>    
<q1:AttachmentID>53c47aba-bb64-4349-a0dc-b00000131105</q1:AttachmentID>  
</q1:Attachment>   
-<q1:Attachment>    
<q1:AttachmentID>3ee501ed-5c5c-43ab-8bd0-b00000131108</q1:AttachmentID>   
</q1:Attachment>  
-<q1:Attachment>    
<q1:AttachmentID>d4fe537a-a95a-4902-a583-b00000131112</q1:AttachmentID>
```

So as you can see there are multiple tags with the same name and I need to store data inside of them, but I don't know how many there will be, given it's different for each XML file. I'm a beginner so please go easy on me if there is an obvious solution, I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach (substring matching on the XML string) is not advisable, you should use one of the XML parsing methods available in Java (SAX, DOM, StAX, JAXB, see [Which is the best library for XML parsing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java)).

**Example using SAX:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class StaxExample {

    public static class CustomSAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        private String senderId;

        private final List<String> attachmentIds = new ArrayList<>();

        private StringBuffer currentCharacters = new StringBuffer();

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            if (currentCharacters != null) {
                currentCharacters.append(String.valueOf(ch, start, length));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                throws SAXException {
            currentCharacters = new StringBuffer();
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            switch (localName) {
            case "AttachmentID":
                getAttachmentIds().add(currentCharacters.toString());
                break;
            case "SenderID":
                setSenderId(currentCharacters.toString());
                break;
            }
            currentCharacters = null;
        }

        public String getSenderId() {
            return senderId;
        }

        public void setSenderId(String senderId) {
            this.senderId = senderId;
        }

        public List<String> getAttachmentIds() {
            return attachmentIds;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(true);
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        CustomSAXHandler saxHandler = new CustomSAXHandler();
        saxParser.parse(StaxExample.class.getResourceAsStream("test.xml"), saxHandler); 
        System.out.println("SenderID: " + saxHandler.getSenderId());
        System.out.println("AttachmentIDs: " + saxHandler.getAttachmentIds());
    }

}
```

**Explanation:**

Parsing a document with SAX requires you to provide a SAX handler, in which you can override certain methods to react on encounters of the different XML elements.

I created a fairly simple custom SAX handler which just records encountered text and stores it in instance variables (senderId, attachmentIds) for later retrieval.

As you see, the senderId is a single String (as it is expected to be encountered only once), and the attachmentIds is a List of Strings to be able to store multiple occurrences.