# How to parse the xml?

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing

I am learning java.
I am unable to parse the below XML using Java. Could someone explain me how to parse this xml?

Even i have tried with some sample code. That didn't work.
I want to read all the present under transaction tag with

- Transaction Id
- amount
- requestedAmount
- status
- Wallet Details

```xml
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns2:getFundAccountHistoryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://schema.products.sports.bet.com/fundingService" xmlns="http://schema.products.sports.bet.com/promoCommonTypes" xmlns:ns3="http://schema.products.sports.bet.com/fundingTypes">
       <ns2:status code="OK" />
       <ns2:transactions>
          <ns3:transaction id="74608009" amount="-200.00" requestedAmount="-200.00" status="COMPLETE">
             <ns3:wallets>
                <ns3:wallet>
                   <ns3:walletType>NON_WITHDRAWABLE</ns3:walletType>
                   <ns3:totalBalance>0.00</ns3:totalBalance>
                </ns3:wallet>
             </ns3:wallets>
             <ns3:transactionFunds>
                <ns3:transactionFund>
                   <ns3:externalFundRef id="CPM-1073070" provider="OB.CUST" />
                   <ns3:transactionFundItems>
                      <ns3:transactionFundItem forfeited="false">
                         <ns3:type>CASH</ns3:type>
                         <ns3:amount>-200.00</ns3:amount>
                      </ns3:transactionFundItem>
                   </ns3:transactionFundItems>
                </ns3:transactionFund>
             </ns3:transactionFunds>
             <ns3:transactionType>BSTK</ns3:transactionType>
             <ns3:creationDate>2019-08-10T17:44:31</ns3:creationDate>
             <ns3:publishedTransactionDate>2019-08-10T17:44:31</ns3:publishedTransactionDate>
             <ns3:transactionDate>2019-08-10T17:44:31</ns3:transactionDate>
             <ns3:fundingActivity>
                <ns3:externalActivityRef id="60077338_0" provider="OB.BET" />
                <ns3:type>STAKE</ns3:type>
                <ns3:fundingOperations>
                   <ns3:fundingOperation>
                      <ns3:externalOperationRef id="b703c6b9-b9aa-4c5d-b6cc-1321d7f2a7a9" provider="OB.BET" />
                      <ns3:operationType>ESB</ns3:operationType>
                      <ns3:status>OPEN</ns3:status>
                   </ns3:fundingOperation>
                </ns3:fundingOperations>
             </ns3:fundingActivity>
             <ns3:description>|Gold Coast Titans| @ 4.75</ns3:description>
          </ns3:transaction>
          <ns3:transaction id="74606629" amount="-411.00" requestedAmount="-411.00" status="COMPLETE">
             <ns3:wallets>
                <ns3:wallet>
                   <ns3:walletType>NON_WITHDRAWABLE</ns3:walletType>
                   <ns3:totalBalance>0.00</ns3:totalBalance>
                </ns3:wallet>
             </ns3:wallets>
             <ns3:transactionFunds>
                <ns3:transactionFund>
                   <ns3:externalFundRef id="CPM-1033856" provider="OB.CUST" />
                   <ns3:transactionFundItems>
                      <ns3:transactionFundItem forfeited="false">
                         <ns3:type>CASH</ns3:type>
                         <ns3:amount>-14.04</ns3:amount>
                      </ns3:transactionFundItem>
                   </ns3:transactionFundItems>
                </ns3:transactionFund>
                <ns3:transactionFund>
                   <ns3:externalFundRef id="CPM-1073070" provider="OB.CUST" />
                   <ns3:transactionFundItems>
                      <ns3:transactionFundItem forfeited="false">
                         <ns3:type>CASH</ns3:type>
                         <ns3:amount>-396.96</ns3:amount>
                      </ns3:transactionFundItem>
                   </ns3:transactionFundItems>
                </ns3:transactionFund>
             </ns3:transactionFunds>
             <ns3:transactionType>BSTK</ns3:transactionType>
             <ns3:creationDate>2019-08-10T17:42:08</ns3:creationDate>
             <ns3:publishedTransactionDate>2019-08-10T17:42:08</ns3:publishedTransactionDate>
             <ns3:transactionDate>2019-08-10T17:42:08</ns3:transactionDate>
             <ns3:fundingActivity>
                <ns3:externalActivityRef id="60076164_0" provider="OB.BET" />
                <ns3:type>STAKE</ns3:type>
                <ns3:fundingOperations>
                   <ns3:fundingOperation>
                      <ns3:externalOperationRef id="9700030e-8057-4ca4-8a1f-74ba9799980d" provider="OB.BET" />
                      <ns3:operationType>ESB</ns3:operationType>
                      <ns3:status>OPEN</ns3:status>
                   </ns3:fundingOperation>
                </ns3:fundingOperations>
             </ns3:fundingActivity>
             <ns3:description>|Over| (49.0) @ 1.87</ns3:description>
          </ns3:transaction>

       </ns2:transactions>
    </ns2:getFundAccountHistoryResponse>
```

I would like to print all the details of under transaction tag.

Comment: What did you try?  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK3000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the best library for XML parsing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java)

Comment: One way to do it is to open a `Stream` at the location of your `xml` file and write everything into a `StringBuilder` then you simply have to convert it to a `String` and then use `split()` function to get the desired tag

Comment: @PhillAlexakis, Could you please show me how?

Comment: @Hari sure i will show you a demo, keep in mind string parsing is a quite long process

Comment: @Hari i suggest you do it with `xml` parser class and not in the way i showed you, but it's up to you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the follow pattern in order to read a `xml` file with two transactions

- Retrieving the `WalletType` Information

```java
 StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
 String sampleLine;
 try(BufferedReader sampleBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./test.xml"))) {
        while ((sampleLine = sampleBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(sampleLine);
            }
 } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  }
//System.out.println(sb.toString());

String content=sb.toString();
String data[]=content.split("<ns3:transaction id=\"74608009\" amount=\"-200.00\" requestedAmount=\"-200.00\" status=\"COMPLETE\">|</ns3:transaction>");
// System.out.println(data[1]+"\n\n");
String seconddata[]=data[1].split("<ns3:walletType>|</ns3:walletType>");
String walletType=seconddata[1];
System.out.println("Wallet Type: "+walletType);
```

> Please keep in mind that this will work just for **two transactions**

As you can see that's how i got the `walletType` attribute from your `xml`, based on what the `split()` method returns you can continue "cutting" the `String` to smaller parts until you get what you would like to have.

- `String data[]=content.split("<ns3:walletType>|</ns3:walletType>");` would also work but you would get the same wallet everytime.

That is why you need to have `two` separate `Strings` containing each transaction.

> Note: This is the **hard** way, you can always do it using and `xml` parser class pick one from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java)

If you get an exception at the `xml` parsing i suggest you insist on solving it, then everything would be much easier. Hope it helps

Comment: @Hari not a problem, it would be highly appreciated if you marked it as an answer

Comment: @NathanHughes it's the "hardcoded" way , that's why i suggested he uses a `parser` class, also the question says that he can't use a parser class, i don't know why

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse XML *will* eventually break.  See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Comment: yes my bad. but if the `xml` is the same it's gonna work, i don't disagree with you