# get attribute value from svg string with java

Tags: java, svg

I have SVG text

```
 <text y="178.0121" x="105.6316" transform="matrix(1.098446574062109,0,0,0.8110834528119214,-14.997837953676935,41.40740441181564) " text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" font-size="20" font-family="Barcode3of9" id="svg_1">reeba</text>
```

Need to get all attributes value and main content as well.
I am trying with substring, Looking for better approach for this.
Thanks

Comment: use an [XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java)

Comment: how we can parse string with xml parser

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/xml/parse-string-to-xml-dom/

Comment: I don't think the XML Parser approach is more performant (or better) than the classic simple way substring.

Comment: With XML Parser attributes are not coming into picture