# Regex that extracts a little text from a huge HTML page and ignore tags and the rest

Tags: html

I want to write a regex which extract the content that only the strings/text in html and i need to remove all the rest. I have a huge webpage with a lot of data, but I will show only a stretch:

```
<div class="flex-row column"><div class="max-360 a-small"> <img class='width-50' src="irobot.io"><h3 class="pad-30">Do you think like a robot?</h3><p> This is not the problem, the problem is about the human failure.</p></div><div class="max-500> <img class='width-50' src="irobot.io"><h3 class="pad-30">
```

"

I need to received back only:

**Do you think like a robot? This is not the problem, the problem is about the human failure.**

Someone can help me? I tried something like:
Regex: **Do you.*[^<]\b<**

But i never worked before with regex.

Thank you!

Comment: What language are you using? Is non regex solution in JS acceptable?

Comment: Could you use the [`innerText`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) or [`textContent`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp) properties instead of [trying to write a regular expression to parse arbitrary HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14956277)?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: you mentioned that you need the solution to work in Python or Java. All my suggestions stay the same; you should use a XML/HTML parser instead of a regular expression. Python has [Lib/xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html), there are [multiple options in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059411/14956277).

If you must use a regular expression, the syntax is the same for Java. In Python, you can use a pattern like `(?:<([^> ]*)[^>]*>)(.*)(?:<\/?\1[^>]*>)` with all the same restrictions I mentioned for JavaScript/Java. [Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/eK1wxN/1)

---

You can try to parse the text contents from a tag using regular expressions, but [it's not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) in most cases. If you must use a regular expression, you can try something like `(?:<(?<tag>[^> ]*)[^>]*>)(?<text>.*)(?:<\/?\k<tag>[^>]*>)` on a single tag at a time.
[Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/Jq203Q/1)

```js
const pattern = /(?:<(?<tag>[^> ]*)[^>]*>)(?<text>.*)(?:<\/?\k<tag>[^>]*>)/;

const matches = pattern.exec(document.body.innerHTML);

console.log('The whole tag: ', matches[0]);
console.log('The tag type: ', matches[1]);
console.log('The text content: ', matches[2]);
```

```html
<h3 class="pad-30">Do you think like a robot?</h3>
```

This will not work over multiple nested tags. There are better options available if you want to parse the whole tree in one action. For instance:

---

The browser's document tree parser already provides [extensive navigation options](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp) including the ability to return the result of concatenating all visible `textNode` contents given a starting node.

You can use the [`innerText`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) or [`textContent`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp) properties like so (open the full screen version):

```js
console.log('Option 1:');
console.log(document.querySelector('body').innerText);

console.log('Option 2:');
console.log(document.querySelector('body').textContent);
```

```css
code {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>Do you <em>need</em> to use a <code>regular expression</code> for this task or would one of the following be suitable?</p>
<ol>
<li>Use the <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp">innerText property</a> of the <code>body</code> node like this: <code>document.querySelector("body").innerText();</code></li>
<li>Use the <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp">textContent property</a> to also get the contents of <code>script</code> tags in the body like this: <code>document.querySelector('body').textContent);</code></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Interesting. I will take a look with your solution! Thank you so much

Comment: Wow, Your answer is amazingly helpful and instructive. Quite possibly one of the best answers I've ever seen, thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This solution helped me a lot!!!! Amazing!